# How to differ an int and a char when using scanf and '%d'

Tags: c, char, int, scanf

I'm writing a program to rotate the letters of a string a certain direction through the alphabet. It takes an initial input of an integer, which I'll call **N**, then uses that integer as the number of letters that each character will be shifted through the alphabet. A positive integer shifts to the right of the alphabet, and a negative integer shifts to the left. For example, if the input was:

```
-2 cdefg
```

the output would be

```
abcde
```

In order to do this, I need to differ between regular alphabetic characters and integers in order to get the initial **N**. I've tried using scanf() with %d and the isalpha() function, as well as %c and the isdigit() function, but both seem to have obstacles for me. To clarify, I'm simply having trouble with the initial variable **N**. I don't know how to tell the difference between an input of 'm' between an integer. To my understanding, it would store the ASCII value of 'm' for **N**.

Comment: To read an integer, use "%d". To read a char, use "%c". You must decide in advance whether you expect to read one or the other. The same string "2" can be parsed as either an integer, or a char, but with quite different results.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read in a whole line of text and store it in an array. You can use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) or – if you have it – [`getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) for this.
2. Then you convert the first “word” on that line to a number using [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol). It tells you the position `end` at which it stopped parsing.
3. Advance the `end` pointer as long as it dereferences to white-space (you can check this via [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace)).
4. Now you're at the position of the first character you need to rotate. Proceed until the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to distinguish them. `N` is always before the string, so just read both, using the appropriate formats.

```
scanf("%d %s", &n, string);
```

To tell if the user entered correct input, check the value that `scanf` returns. It returns the number of items successfully converted. If the user doesn't type an integer first, the `%d` conversion will fail, so it will return `0`. If the user types a valid integer before the string, it will return `2`.

Comment: I'm trying to differ the different types of inputs for **N**. If the user was to input 'm' instead of an integer, I'm not sure how to differentiate that from a regular integer. If I use isdigit(), it leaves out all numbers greater than 9 and all negative numbers, which are all valid for **N**.

Comment: That will just cause a conversion failure. Check the return value of `scanf`. If it's not 2, it means the user didn't enter correctly formatted input.